# How to create a Bounce Effect with GWT?

Tags: gwt

I know many methods to add a Bounce Effect to an Image or a Div with jQuery, jQueryUi and so on. But its there a typical GWT Way to add Bounce Effect to an Element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well!! i resolve it using [CSS3 animations](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/bouncing-ball-animation/#.US8tzmfDuno)

Answer (score 1):

[GWT-FX](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-fx/) is a effects library for GWT, it includes some pre-built [transition effect](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-fx/wiki/BasicUserGuide#Transitioning_Effects) that you can use.

You can also use `jQuery` or `jQueryUi` in your GWT application using JSNI.